# For Loop Doesn't Work Right

Tags: java

Why doesn't this for loop count the right number of times? If I set the variable `runs` to 3, the loops runs 4 times. (One extra case.)

Thanks in advance!

```
for (int i = runs; i >= 0; i--)
{
   System.out.println("Input Duration of Trip");
   Scanner timeCalc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Hours ==> ");
   int hour = timeCalc.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Minutes ==> ");
   int minute = timeCalc.nextInt();
   System.out.println("You entered: " + hour + " hour(s) and " + minute + " minutes");
   System.out.println();
   time = convertHoursMinutesToDouble(hour, minute);
   totalTime += time;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in

```
i>=0
```

What the code is doing is going "Ok, i is going to be equal to three. Now, let's see, ok, back up again, subtract one, i =2... subtract one i=1... Now tricky tricky it SKIPS the termination part of the code because it looks at it first BEFORE substracting one so i=0, ok WAIT i=0 so STOP."

Solution?

```
for (int i = runs; **i >= 1**; i--)
```

This mistake always messes me up.
Hope the whole "through the mind of the computer thing" doesn't bother you. That's how I tend to think.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

The loop runs for values:

```
3
2
1
0
```

That's 4 times.

If you want it to run for values 3, 2 and 1, you can change your for loop to:

```
for (int i = runs; i > 0; i--)
```

or

```
for (int i = runs; i >= 1; i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i == 3
i >= 0
println

i--
i == 2
i >= 0
println

i--
i == 1
i >= 0
println

i--
i == 0
i >= 0
println
```

That was 4 times. You need your condition to be: i > 0

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set greater than or equal to...

So starts at 3 and goes, 2,1,0.